# Search an object, a image or rectangle and add image on it in java with iText

Tags: object, pdf, search, itext

I'm using Itext to add an image to a PDF File. I added the image but I don't want it in an absolute position because I have lots of different reports. I think to put an image in the pdf and change it but it didn't work for me.

That's my code now with absolute position:

```
    ByteSource pdfVersion = remoteAccess.loadMultimedia(signature.getIdMultimedia());
    // Imagen
    Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("src/main/resources/signFolder"));
    File img = new File("src/main/resources/signFolder/" + fileName);
    img.deleteOnExit();
    com.google.common.io.Files.write(file.read(), img);
    // Pdf
    File pdf = new File("src/main/resources/signFolder/" + signature.getIdMultimedia());
    com.google.common.io.Files.write(pdfVersion.read(), pdf);

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf.getPath());
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
            new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/signFolder/with_image.pdf"));
    Image image = Image.getInstance(img.getPath());
    PdfImage stream = new PdfImage(image, "", null);
    stream.put(new PdfName("ITXT_SpecialId"), new PdfName("123456789"));
    PdfIndirectObject ref = stamper.getWriter().addToBody(stream);
    image.setDirectReference(ref.getIndirectReference());
    image.setAbsolutePosition(36, 270);
    image.scalePercent(50);
    PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
    over.addImage(image);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

I thought to search a rectangle in the PDF file. Do you know how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to reinvent [pdfSweep](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfsweep) using an old version of iText. Why are you using an old iText version? Are you aware of the iText 7 add-on pdfSweep? This add-on allows you to search for content based on a pattern and to physically remove that content (not merely cover it) and put a colored rectangle in its place. That's close to what you want to do.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I will chanche iText to pdfSweep. I didn't know that it was an old version. Thank you so much.

Comment: Er... pdfSweep is an add-on, so don't change iText to pdfSweep. Upgrade to iText 7 and examine pdfSweep. I don't know if it will solve your problem, because I don't know *why* you want to cover specific content.

Comment: Yes sorry @BrunoLowagie , I change to 7.1 Version.  I'm working in a signature service with spring and now I'm trying to find images in the pdf with a specific ID because sometimes we want to put only one image (the signature contact) or sometimes more than one. I just need to study how to differentiate between the different images in the pdf.

Comment: I think that I found what I wanted in other post but It is with iText 5